# SCORM 2004 Get and Set Values

Tags: javascript, scorm, scorm2004

I am trying to get and set the completion status of various objectives. I am trying to do these;

```
str = scorm.GetValue("cmi.objectives." + i.toString() + ".completion_status");
```

---

```
GetValue('cmi.objectives.0.completion_status') returned '' in 0 seconds
[13:50:23.469] Checking for GetValue Error
[13:50:23.469] SCORM ERROR FOUND - Set Error State: 301 - 
The Objectives collection does not have an element at index 0, the current element count is 0.
```

---

This is the log of SCORM Cloud. I think it might be related to giving IDs to objectives.

My objectives are not set ID in manifest and I don't know I have to do it. So the question is do I need to give an ID to each objective (manifest or javascript)?

If you think/guess/know the problem is completely different, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Not related to specifying an ID. The SCORM log error says the objective doesn't exist. Verify that the objective exists via _count as described by Mark below.

Comment: The ```i.toString()``` is redundant - just use ```i``` directly as javascript itself will change it into a string.

Comment: @Rycochet actually it is AS  and it does not like integer there. But I didn't know JS can auto cast.

Comment: The auto casting can be useful - such as doing maths on a string of a number - but I only ever trust autocasting to string ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So typically you could check -
scorm.GetValue('cmi.objectives._count') to know if you had any objectives to poll.

If it came back with 2, you would then have two objectives to loop thru to look for the cmi.objective.x.id you needed to update.  Or, if your adding a new objective, that _count would give you the next available index in the packed array.

If you had a _count of 1 it would be worth trying to check for completion_status etc ...  Otherwise you'll generate SCORM Errors like the one you described.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The count return was 0 so no objectives. Better check completion_status and all loops.

Comment: Great, so I have a 'getObjectiveByID' type lookup so if you are resuming a SCO and need to look up the array value of an objective it can return the object back.  That code is all open source at https://github.com/cybercussion/SCOBot/blob/master/QUnit-Tests/js/scorm/SCOBotBase.js

Comment: Wow, that will work for sure. I actually have solved my problem already but definitely give a try later on. Thanks one more time.

Answer (score 1):

It's a requirement to set the id first before setting (or getting) other values - see REQ_72.4.2.6 in the [SCORM Conformance Requirements](http://www.adlnet.gov/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/SCORM.2004.3ED.ConfReq.v1.0.pdf) (around page 50).

It is quite ok to set the id within javascript, so you could quite easily use `"objective_1"` for the first etc (though for more future proof it should be some form of URN instead - even if that's `"urn:x-local:objective_1"`).